# Why aren't unions with literal types and {} widened?

Tags: typescript

In the following example, why isn't `Test3` reduced to `{}`, while the others are reduced to the widest member of the union?

```
type Test1 = "a" | "b" | string // => string
type Test2 = "a" | "b" | any // => any
type Test3 = "a" | "b" | {} // => "a" | "b" | {}
```

`{}` [means any non-nullish value](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492), which means these are all completely valid:

```
const test1: any = "hello, world!"
const test2: string = "hello, world!"
const test3: {} = "hello, world!"
```

Intuitively, then, it feels like `{}` should behave the same way as `string` and `any` when put in a union with other string literal types. That is, reducing the union to the type of the "widest" member.

Why is that not the case?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that also the use case of the types is different

While `{}` means any non-nullish value and has a type check `any` (according to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) ) means "whatever you want" and you have to use it

> whenever you don’t want a particular value to cause typechecking errors

So when using `any` in a union type it is like it "removes" the type checking

Comment: Thank you! Is `{}` not a super set of `"a"`, though, since `"a"` can be assigned to it? Or am I perhaps misunderstanding the relationship between "assignable" and "super set"?

Comment: You're almost there! ```{}``` is a super set of ```{ foo: string }``` because ```{ foo: string }``` can be represented by ```{}``` but the literal ```"a"``` (or the ```string``` type in general ) cannot be represented by ```object``` least of all by ```{}``` . That said you can of course assign ```"a"``` to the object! Hope that this will answer to your question! :)

Comment: Sorry, I must be having a slow day today. If you don't mind, could you explain what "represented by" means (feel free to show with code)? 

Thank you for your patience, I think this is the last piece of the puzzle, so I'll make sure to accept your answer when this finally clicks!

Comment: Sure! No problem! ```{}``` means "any object" so ```{ foo: string }``` is included in "any object" as ```any``` includes all the types. Imagine talking about the category "programmers" by the word programmer are represented all the frontend, backend and full stack developers, right? same for ```{}``` ! this means "every object" so also ```{ foo: string }``` is included.  The literal type, like ```"a"``` and any other ```string``` (or in general any other primitive apart from ```object``` )  are not objects so cannot be represented by the type ```object```

Comment: Ah, I think the example I included was a bit misleading – sorry. I understand that it represents any object, but it's my understanding that `{}` _also_ means [_any non-nullish value_](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492), which implies that `string` and friends are included. This is why I don't understand why the union is not being reduced to `{}`.  E.g.: This is valid TS: `const test: {} = "a"`, since `"a"` kind of is an object at runtime (because JavaScript wraps it in `String()` so that we can do `.toLowerCase`).

Comment: I have updated my original post to hopefully convey my problem a bit better. Again, appreciate your responses!